# RestSharp API for Form logon always returns OK

Tags: c#, python, forms, post, restsharp

I am trying to convert the submit.py  Application from Open Kattis. It logs on to site and submits a file. Perfect Spec for RestSharp!!! What am I doing wrong?

I am just trying the login portion:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://open.kattis.com");

        var request = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("user", "mark-wardell");
        request.AddParameter("token", "XXXX");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

I always get back httpStatus OK. This happens wether i put the correct token or not. When I alter the values provided to submit.py variables i get meaningful responses. submit.py is here [ [Download Submit.py](https://open.kattis.com/download/submit.py) ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block works...

```
var client = new RestClient("https://open.kattis.com");
            var req = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);
            var config = new ClientConfig();//values to pass in request

            // Content type is not required when adding parameters this way
            // This will also automatically UrlEncode the values
            //req.AddBody(config);

            req.AddParameter("script", config.script, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            req.AddParameter("token", config.token, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            req.AddParameter("user", config.user, ParameterType.GetOrPost);


            var res = client.Execute(req);
            await Task.Delay(10);
            return true;
```